# OnSubmit not called if file not chosen

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms

I am new to react. I have a form that supposed to display an alert box showing information about the input details when form is submitted. And it does, but only if a file is selected.

All the other related questions I have come across on SO do not tackle this issue

```
import React, {createRef} from "react";
import {render} from "react-dom";


class TheForm extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = {text: ""};
        this.handleTextChange = this.handleTextChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.fileInputRef = createRef();
    }
    render()
    {
        return (<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <input type="text" onChange={this.handleTextChange}
            value={this.state.text}/>
            <br />
            <input type="file" ref={this.fileInputRef} />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Go!" 
            style={{fontFamily: "segoe UI", cursor: "pointer"}} />
            </form>);
    }
    handleTextChange(e)
    {
        this.setState({text: e.target.value});
    }
    handleSubmit(e)
    {
        alert(this.state.text + " " + this.fileInputRef.current.files[0].name);
        this.setState({text: ""});
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}

render (<TheForm />, document.querySelector("body"));
```

If a file is selected, the code works fine. If a file is not selected, onSubmit will not even be called. What really is wrong?

Comment: Here are some debug tips: check the browser dev console first when you have problems to see what's up. If you're a beginner, try adding `console.log()` or `alert()` statements at various places to see if the code there is running or what the state is. When you get a little more comfortable, learn how to use `debugger;` statements or browser debugger/breakpoints to step through your code. Be careful about accessing properties on objects and arrays when the value might be undefined.

Comment: Yeah, that was silly of me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the dev console in the browser when you run your code? I can almost guarantee that you're getting an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` because of this line:

```
alert(this.state.text + " " + this.fileInputRef.current.files[0].name);
```

If you haven't selected a file yet, `this.fileInputRef.current.files` is an empty array, so you can't access `files[0].name`. You'll get a TypeError and crash your app.

Try checking for the existence of the file first before trying to access its name:

```
const fileName = this.fileInputRef.current.files[0] ? this.fileInputRef.current.files[0].name : "No file selected.";
alert(this.state.text + " " + fileName);
```

Or you could do a try/catch:

```
let fileName = "";
try {
  fileName = this.fileInputRef.current.files[0].name;
} catch(e) {
  fileName = "No file selected";
}
alert(this.state.text + " " + fileName);
```